# Alternative proof that adding an additional square root of the identity to the free group on one generator results in a non-Abelian group

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof, group-actions, free-groups

I'll be using additive notation for groups regardless of whether the group in question is Abelian or not.

I am thinking about the consequences of adding propertyless square roots of existing elements to groups.

Right now I'm interested in cases where the Abelianness of the group in question is preserved or not preserved.

Let $G$ be the free group generated by $a$.

If we add a new element $b$ such that $b+b=a$, then the group that we get back is isomorphic to $G$.

If our new element $b$ satisfies $b+b = 0$, then it is less clear whether the resulting group is Abelian or not.

I have a proof that I think works using an infinite permutation of the integers.

Let $a$ correspond to the two-place relation $xAy$ defined to be true precisely when $x = y + 1$.

Let $b$ correspond to the two-place relation $xBy$ defined as $B = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\} \cup \{ (x, y) : x = y \land x \not \in \{0, 1\} \}$, i.e. $b$ swaps $0$ and $1$ and leaves the rest of the elements alone.

I claim that the group generated by $A$ and $B$ is not Abelian.

$2 (A \circ B) 0$ holds but $2 (B \circ A) 0$ fails.

This permutation representation is a valid interpretation of $\langle a, b \mid b^2 = 0 \rangle$, and it serves to show that the freest interpretation of $\langle a, b \mid b^2 = 0 \rangle$ is not Abelian regardless of whether it is the freest interpretation or not. (I think the permutation representation does correspond to the freest interpretation of $\langle a, b \mid b^2 = 0 \rangle$, but I don't know how to prove it.)

Anyway, finding this infinite permutation representation was slightly tricky, so I'm **wondering whether there are other ways to show that adjoining an additional square root of $0$ results in a non-Abelian group, especially ones that are more general or do not involve giving a concrete interpretation to the group.**

Comment: How is the composition of relations defined?

Comment: @colt_browning, $x(R \circ S)y$ holds if and only if there exists a $z$ so that $xRz$ and $zRy$. Also, it occurred to me after writing this that this permutation representation thing is the same thing as (and might better be described as) a group action.

Comment: I agree, about group actions. $a$ moves everything up by one, $b$ swaps zero and one. $ab(0)=a(1)=2$, $ba(0)=b(1)=0$, so $ab\ne ba$.

Answer (score 4):

Adding a "propertyless square root" to a given group is equivalent to taking a [free product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_product) of the given group with the group $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$. So, your question is equivalent to asking whether the free product $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is abelian.

The general fact is that any free product of two nontrivial groups is nonabelian. The best proof I know uses [Bass-Serre theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bass%E2%80%93Serre_theory) to concretely realize the group by an action on a tree ("best" meaning, here, that you learn a very nice and very powerful theory with lots of applications).

If you want a method which does not involve giving a "concrete interpretation" to the group, you're not going to be satisfied with that. But, frankly, representing groups "concretely" is the textbook way to identify many groups, including free products. The general method is to learn something about a mysterious group $G$ by using a presentation for $G$ by generators and relators to construct a "representation" of $G$, meaning a homomorphism $G \mapsto \Gamma$ to some other more well-known group $\Gamma$ (which can be a permutation group, or a matrix group, or anything, really). One reason why this is so useful is that once one correctly guesses how to define the representation on each generator of $G$, each relator can be easily verified to hold in $\Gamma$ by using whatever well known method of computation there might be in the group $\Gamma$.

---

In this case you can also see more simply that $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is nonabelian by representing it in the group of rigid motions of the real number line, i.e. all functions of the form $x \mapsto \pm x + t$:
$$a \to (x \mapsto x+1) \qquad b \
\to (x \mapsto -x)
$$
The only relator that needs to be checked is $b^2 = \text{Id}$ (I cannot bring myself to write $b^2=0$... eeerghhh, I wrote it...), and obviously the composition of $x \mapsto -x$ with itself is the identity.

On a side note, this representation of $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is not injective: it satisfies an additional relator $bab=a^{-1}$ which is not satisfied in $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$; its image is the infinite dihedral group. If one is interested, there is a more clever injective representation of $\mathbb Z * \mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ in the group $PSL(2,\mathbb R)$ of fractional linear transformation $x \mapsto \frac{px + q}{rx + t}$ ($pt-qr=1$).

Comment: Non-abelianness can also be shown by establishing a normal form for elements in the free product, but I don't remember how difficult this is.

Comment: From the Bass-Serre point of view, that normal form is a corollary of the desription of the tree action. But there are other, nongeometric deductions of that normal form.

Comment: @LeeMosher thanks for this amazing answer; I have one small comment. I'm only adding the propertyless square root to a single element. I looked at adding $\sqrt{a}$ briefly and at adding $\sqrt{0}$. Does the equivalence with the free product of $G$ with $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ apply to taking the square root of $0$, taking the square root of every element, or both?

Comment: From the point of view of a presentation of a group by generators and relators, you can do either one of those. In general, if you are given a particular group element $g$ expressed as the product of a sequence of generators denoted $w$, to add a square root of $g$ you add one generator --- call it $a$ --- and one relator expressed either as an equation $a^2 = w$ or as an equation $a^2 w^{-1} = \text{Id}$. But if $g$ is not the identity then this is *not* a free product.

Answer (score 2):

One can also note that every dihedral group satisfies your presentation. It follows that every dihedral group is a quotient of the group defined by your presentation. Since there are nonabelian dihedral groups, your group is also nonabelian. (Strictly speaking, noticing this for a single nonabelian dihedral group suffices.)